# ASP.NET Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have event that basically checks if I have already added to  shipment already. I put a break point in at `inventoryBLL inv = new inventoryBLL();` and it never breaks. The funny thing is that I can get the index without much fuss.

My C#

```
    protected void rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        inventoryBLL inv = new inventoryBLL();
        List<string> asinholder = new List<string>();
        List<string> fnskuholder = new List<string>();


        int Index = new int();
        asinwrapper asin = asinwrapper.GetSessionWrapper();
        if (asin != null)
        {
            fnskuholder = asin.FNSKU;
            asinholder = asin.ASIN;
            Index = asin.Index;

        }
        List<shipmentdetail> detail = new List<shipmentdetail>();
        multipleshipments m = multipleshipments.GetSessionWrapper();
        if (m != null)
        {
            detail = m.Detail;
        }
        inventory.ItemCheckDataTable items = inv.GetItem(asinholder[Index], detail[0].Id[ddlExisting1.SelectedIndex]);
        if (items.Rows.Count < 0)
        {
            foreach (inventory.ItemCheckRow row in items)
            {
                txt.Text = row.Quantity;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the HTML

```
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSwitch1" runat="server" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">New Shipment</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Existing Shipment</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: do u mean it breaks at the statement where index is present

Comment: It's not firing a postback when you click on a listItem is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack = "true"` to your tag.  This should be it:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSwitch1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
  onselectedindexchanged="rblSwitch1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
 <asp:ListItem Value="0">New Shipment</asp:ListItem> 
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">Existing Shipment</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[Here is a decent reference showing an example.](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-autopostback-feature-in_18.html)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not caused by `AutoPostBack` of the control being set to false, check if `AutoEventWireup` is set false. It can be set in several places, including page header and config files.